# Is there a proof of the Green-Sibson algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, voronoi-diagram

I was introduced to Voronoi Diagram and espacially the Green-Sibson algorithm ([Here](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Compgeometry/MyCG/Voronoi/Incremental2/incremental2.htm)). I couldn't find their paper so I'm looking for a proof of the algorithm.

One particular problem I have is that it seems to change the diagram locally and doesn't take into account all the points. Furthermore, I don't really understand how the new edges are built.

Thanks for your answers.